# How to inherit a user object in power builder but the inherited object should be used as a data window.

Tags: powerbuilder

How to inherit a user object in power builder but the inherited object should be used as a data window. How to achieve this? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Power builder 12.6 is the version that is used and I have section that reads as follows: **dw_xyz (datawindow) inherited from u_xyz(user object)**

Am familiar with the concept of inheriting from a user object or a window, i.e, **w_child inherited from w_parent** or **u_child inherited from u_parent**. But how the above mentioned case is possible?

A similar functionality needs to be included. (**dw_xyz inherited from u_xyz**)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user object of type datawindow and inherit from it.  If your existing user object is of a different type you can edit it (use edit source or export/edit/import) so that it inherits from datawindow and then regenerate the descendants and you are good to go.

There are more standard methods in the datawindow class vs the user object class but that is largely irrelevant since most user objects have user created methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using PowerBuilder 12.6. You cannot inherit a datawindow from a user object. Datawindows and Userobject are completely different. What you can do is have a Datawindow (DW1) and a UserObject (U1) and create functions/code in the user object that will do whatever you want inside the datawindow. I'm not sure how your workspace is setup but that's how I use powerbuilder. Each Datawindow has a user object that goes with it. The code is in the user object and display in the datawindow.

This link will explain more how datawindows and userobject go together.
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37775.1252/html/dwprgug/CAIDADAJ.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes the data window and user objects are completely different. But I have one existing functionality itself in my code, that works as I mentioned above. The properties section of the datawindow reads as **dw_xyz inherited from u_xyz** and that is confusing me. 

As you said, we can include the functionality in user object. Yes I have done that, but I have a drop down item in the data window and on click of that drop down, I expect an operation to be happening. And this coding I have done inside the clicked event of that data window.

Comment: @Sathya I see, so you are including some code inside the datawindow. Is it JavaScript code? And what are you trying to do? make a datawindow by inheriting it from a user object? Ill open my PB and see if I can get something to work

Comment: Yes please check and let me know whether you can find something on how that is possible. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, if I can read something as **dw_xyz inherited from u_xyz** in the properties section, then I guess it should be possible. I have not seen this before and am not sure how was this possible before. 

The user object has the existing functionality of getting the column_name and setting the column_name from the click event of the drop down ..

Answer (score 0):

The more typical way of doing what you're asking is to put the code to be shared in a non-visual object, and have each object wanting to use that code instantiate the NVO and call it. I'd imagine you'll likely have to change the code a little to accommodate creating a reference to the parent object and using that reference. If you want code examples [PFC](http://pfc.codeplex.com/) services are built that way.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection may be off. I *think* you can create a visual user object and then add a datawindow to it. Then, any time you need a datawindow, add an instance of this user object. (Or maybe inherit from it.) You can then add functions to the object to control the datawindow. It's been a while since I did PowerBuilder, so that might be off, but I've done something like that before.

Comment: Exactly!. And yes I did find such a thing in my initial search of how to setup this. So to be clear on my expected behavior-- 
I have a visual user object already existing **(u_xyz)**  and I have a new datawindow **dw_abc** , my property section should read as **dw_abc inherited from u_xyz** .. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help on this. I have found the way to get this done. The following operation will result in the creation of a datawindow which will be inherited from a userobject. (**The properties section will read dw_abc inherited from u_abc**)

**Insert->Control->UserObject**